# Writing variables to .txt after setup is done

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to write a variable to the DestDir after setup is done?

i want to store a variable to a text file with:

```
SaveStringToFile('c:\filename.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);
```

Is there a function like function InitializeSetup(): Boolean; for the end of the setup process?

I want to save this text file to the DestDir Directory

Comment: As there is no single `DestDir` directory, you can use `ExpandConstants('{app}\filename.txt')`

Answer (score 3):

You might call your code from [`CurStepChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) event method when the `CurStep` parameter equals to [`ssDone`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=TSetupStep). In pseudo code it would look like this:

```
[Code]    
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
    SaveStringToFile('c:\filename.txt', #13#10 + 'the string' + #13#10, True);
end;
```

Comment: @user1327352 - remember you can mark TLama's answer as "Accepted" - just click the V mark under Answer points.